# What is the difference between channelFlow and callbackFlow

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand why we need callbackFlow builder, it seems almost same with channelFlow except callbackFlow is inline. What is the use case ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing. One of them literally calls the other. The difference is in the intention. It is supposed to make your code more self documenting about your intentions.

Use callback flow for callbacks and channelFlow for concurrent flow emission.

EDIT:
As of [Version 1.3.4](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/CHANGES.md#flow), `callbackFlow` will detect missing calls to `awaitClose`, making it less error prone.
So they are now different.

Comment: This is not a satisfying reason according to me. For example List.getFirst() make sense, it prevents duplicate code. But in this case there should something more meaningful.

Comment: To me it makes sense because the same underlying logic happens to cover two very different use cases. However, a note in the docs would be very useful to avoid confusion. BTW `callbackFlow` doesn't even call `channelFlow`, it compiles into a direct call to it, basically it's an alias.

Comment: Ok then I accepted the answer, maybe they should improve docs for better understanding as you said.

Comment: They are still experimental. Maybe in the future differences will apear.

Comment: There aren't any noticeable differences.